# JPQL Oder by Map value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have next entity:

```
@Entity
public class Condition {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<String,String> parameters;

    // Setters and Getters
}
```

and i want to make a JPQL to return rows sorted by Map value of **parameters**

When i created the query like that:

```
SELECT model FROM Condition model LEFT JOIN model.parameters parameter ORDER BY VALUE(parameter)
```

i got an error of **ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

So how i can sort by Map value ?? is it possible?